# bootstrap not full screen in iPhone 5

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, ios6

I am designing a pretty standard mobile version of a website using bootstrap3, and it works as expected for every phone I can test on, EXCEPT the iPhone5 - there seems to be a small gap down the right hand side of the screen.

A screenshot is available here http://sigwebdesign.com/screenshot.jpg

I was wondering if this is a common issue, and if there is something I need to add to the code to compensate for it?

Comment: please post your code or a link to the website

Comment: absolutely, it is at http://sigsample.info/glenalpinephone/index.php  thankyou

Comment: how does your menu appear in your iphone 5?

Comment: in the screnshot at http://sigwebdesign.com/screenshot.jpg yuou can see that there is some form of padding down the right hand side, In other phones I have tried (iphone 4 and razor) as well as resizining the desktop screen this padding does not occur

Comment: Try adding overflow-x:hidden